# Add multiple images at once

Tags: channel-images, ee4

I am using Channel Images v 7.0.0 with EE 4.2

The capability to add multiple images at once - that is intended for just **one** channel entry, correct?

For example, I have a page showing a company's Staff Members - the HTML mock-up is [here](http://www.vanhove.net/gng/about.html).

I thought I could upload all the staff images at once into a designated file directory and then select the image assigned to each member/channel entry.

But that does not seem to be the case, am I right - ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Channel Images is not made to select pre uploaded images. Basically it does not even have any proper destination to store images. When you create an entry, EE generates Entry ID for that entry and channel images creates new directory for that entry to store those images. Thus it is not possible to just select photos.

You can't even use Assets as an alternative as I show your HTML mockup, It has title, job designation and description with each image.

You now need to use channel images like that or you can switch to normal file field with GRID (You can upload all images at once via FTP in your upload directory and sync it from EE file manager)